# Change HTML action="" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the string inside action="somthing" I've tried using

```
document.getElementsByClassName
```

but it doesn't seems to change anything.

My HTML

```
......
.........
<div class="my_button button" action='play_car'></div>
 .....
......
```

My Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my_button').action = "play_boat";
.......
......
```

I've also tried
HTML

```
<div id="test" class="my_button button" action='play_car'></div>
```

Javascript

```
   var a= document.getElementById('test');
   console.log(a);
```

It just returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["get element-*s* by class name"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a collection, not a single element.

> *Returns an array of all child elements which have any of the given class names.* When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node.

Assuming that there is only a single element returned, then:

```
var elementsWithClass = document.getElementsByClassName('my_button')
elementsWithClass[0].action = "play_boat";
```

However, it may be more appropriate to use a loop - class names are generally designed to be used with *multiple* elements, and IDs (along with `getElementById`) for singular/unique elements.

Unfortunately, `getElementsByClassName` is [*not supported*](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) in even as "recent" a browser as IE8. To handle this, use a cross-browser library (jQuery or your preference) or a polyfill.

Comment: Thank for the help! but I'm getting this error 'TypeError: elementsWithClass[0] is undefined'

Comment: @user3159101 Then there were no matching elements found - and elementsWithClass.length is 0 (accessing the undefined array index returns undefined in JavaScript). Make sure the script is run *after* the relevant DOM is available.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName will return an array of all elements. Use document.getElementById if you want to address only one element. Also getElementsByClassName isn't supported by older browser. If that's an issue, you can use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one element with this class name, you can get the first item:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my_button')[0].action = "play_boat";
```

if you have many, iterate over them:

```
for (var i in document.getElementsByClassName('my_button')) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('my_button')[i].action = "play_boat"; 
}
```

Please, check if the place of the javascript code is after the elements with the class "my_button".

Comment: so you can iterate over them.

Comment: I totally would be I get this error when I try your code   TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined

Comment: @user3159101 Then there were no matching elements found - and elementsWithClass.length is 0 (accessing the undefined array index returns undefined in JavaScript). Make sure the script is run after the relevant DOM is available.